# what's the storage format of protobuf data?

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers

the .proto file:

```
package lm;
message helloworld
{
     required int32 id = 1;
     required string str = 2;
     optional int32 opt = 3;
}
```

the writer.cc file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "lm.helloworld.pb.h"
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    lm::helloworld msg1;
    msg1.set_id(101000);
    msg1.set_str("helloworld,this is a protobuf writer");
    fstream output("log", ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);
    string _data;
    msg1.SerializeToString(&_data);
    cout << _data << endl;
    if(!msg1.SerializeToOstream(&output))
    {
        cerr << "Failed to write msg" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the reader.cc file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "lm.helloworld.pb.h"
using namespace std;

void ListMsg(const lm::helloworld & msg)
{
    cout << msg.id() << endl;
    cout << msg.str() << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    lm::helloworld msg1;
    {
        fstream input("log", ios::in | ios::binary);
        if (!msg1.ParseFromIstream(&input))
        {
            cerr << "Failed to parse address book." << endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }

    ListMsg(msg1);
    return 0;
}
```

It's a simple reader and writer model using protobuf. but what's in the log is a readable string a typed in the write.cc file instead of "numeric format",why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The encoding is described here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding).

Without an example of what comes out the other end, that is slightly hard to answer precisely, but there are two possible explanations of what you are seeing:

1. you have explicitly switched into [`TextFormat`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.text_format) in your code; this is very unlikely - and indeed, the primary use of `TextFormat` is debugging etc
2. far more likely, you're just seeing the text data *from your message* in the binary; text is encoded as UTF-8, so if you open a protobuf file in a text editor, pieces of it will appear *readable enough* to display something in the file

The real question is: what are the *actual bytes* in your output file? If it is something like:

> 08-88-95-06-12-24-68-65-6C-6C-6F-77-6F-72-6C-64-2C-74-68-69-73-20-69-73-20-61-20-70-72-6F-74-6F-62-75-66-20-77-72-69-74-65-72

then that *is* the binary format; but note that most of that is simply the UTF-8 of the string `"helloworld,this is a protobuf writer"` - which dominates the message by sheer size:

> 68-65-6C-6C-6F-77-6F-72-6C-64-2C-74-68-69-73-20-69-73-20-61-20-70-72-6F-74-6F-62-75-66-20-77-72-69-74-65-72

So if you look in any text editor, it will appear as a few garbled characters at the start followed by the clearly legible `helloworld,this is a protobuf writer`.

The "binary" here is the bit at the start:

> 08-88-95-06-12-24

This is:

- 08: header: field 1, varint
- 88-95-06: the value (decimal) 101000 as a varint
- 12: header: field 2, length-prefixed
- 24: the value (decimal) 36 as a varint (the length of the string, in bytes)

The key points to note:

- if your message is dominated by text, the yes, large parts of it will look human-readable even in binary form
- look at the overheads; it to 6 bytes to encode the *entire rest of the message*, and 3 bytes of that was data (the 101000) - so only 3 bytes was actually lost as overhead; now compare and contrast to xml, json, etc to understand what protobuf is doing to help you